# How to Add text after End drawable in Materialtextinput Android

Tags: android, android-drawable

[image]

I would like to add text like this, is this possible with MaterialLayout & MaterialTextInput ??

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in two ways.

The more complicated way is to extend the MaterialTextInput and override methods.

The simple way is to put the MaterialTextInput in a FrameLayout along with a TextView with a fixed size. Create a same size dummy Drawable (eg: ColorDrawable) and set it as end drawable.

Comment for further information.

Comment: thanks for the answer, becuase of my personal project i left it, tried to change STYLES file and it worked.